# ValueError: cannot set a Timestamp with a non-timestamp str

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I switched devices recently and installed anaconda on my new device to get my python script running in spyder.
Now, the code I used on the initial device seems to give an error on the new device. (both IOS)
The received error is mentioned in the title.

The error is thrown when running the following line:

`a.at[i, 'date'] = datetime.strftime(ref_date - timedelta(int(ref_day - a.at[i, 'day'])),'%Y-%m-%d')`

When I printed the different elements in the code on both devices, I received exactly the same output.

```
print (ref_date)
print (timedelta(int(ref_day - a.at[i, 'day'])))
print (a.at[i, 'day'])
```

With output:

```
2020-06-24 00:00:00
1 day, 0:00:00
1
```

Python version of the new device:
`3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) [Clang 10.0.0 ]`

Python version of the old device:
`3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]`

Hope one of you guy's can help.

Regards

Andries

Comment: what is `a`? a `pandas.DataFrame`? if so, when changing devices, did you update/change pandas version?

Comment: Thanks for the input, could solve the issue! `a` is indeed a `pandas.DataFrame`.  I already tried `conda install pandas==0.25.1`, but my pandas is installed on pip so that didn´t do anything.